# How to incude files runtime in PHP

Tags: php, include

I want to include different files, depending on a parameter passed to `get` method. E.g. if the `id` passed in the URL is `101` then I want to include `file_101.php`. Here is what I have so far:

```
if(cat_id == 101)
{
    $filename="file_101.php";
}

//some code here
include('$filename');
```

I have also tried:

```
include('echo $filename;');
```

but it is giving error

> include() [function.include]: Unable to access echo $filename;

Comment: I like these kinds of questions where the syntax is so messed up by people still learning - it makes me remember that learning to program isn't easy in the beginning, which i tend to forget after programming for so many years it becomes a second language next to english :)

Comment: Don't use the quotes. Just leave it as a variable **include($file)** and it should be fine. I used it some time ago back in uni.

Answer (score 6):

Get rid of the single quotes. They make PHP parse the `$` as a literal dollar sign instead of the beginning of a variable name.

```
include($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your echo is too many! You can include file with:

```
include 'file.php';
```

Or you can use methods that others have written.

Replace with $cat_id cat_id also!

PS. I counsel you to specify the name of the file that you include without variables.